# Adding additional seconds in Timer's interval

Tags: vb.net, timer

Supposedly, I have a timer which has a value of 5000 (5secs). After 5 seconds,

```
Radiobutton1.Enabled = False
Radiobutton2.Enabled = False
```

will be locked. What I want to happen is when I click a certain button, (`Button1` for example), It will add another 2000 (2seconds) and my Radiobuttons 1 and 2, again will be enabled again.

My Timer1 code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Timer1.Stop()
        RadioButton1.Enabled = False
        RadioButton2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm so sorry. Will not happen again.

Comment: Are you telling us that you're unfamiliar with the `+` operator?

Comment: You don't know how much time as passed so you don't know what to set the Interval to.  You need to fix that by storing DateTime.UtcNow in a variable when you enable the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button click event add:

```
Timer1.Interval += 2000
RadioButton1.Enabled = True
RadioButton2.Enabled = True
Timer1.Enabled = True 'If you want to start the timer again
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).